# How to cancel the Magnifying glass function of a webview?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uiwebview

In webview of my app , I found that when click it for few moments , it will show a Magnifying glass, how to cancel this function in my app , thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable text selection also, you can simply add this css to your document:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```